Filter multiple rows to a single row
I have a table DrData that stores doctor data. One doctor can have multiple rows on this table. One row for each location they provide services for within a healthcare system. On this table there is a column named DrStartDt and DrEndDt. I am writing an extract that only wants one row in the output per doctor. In my output I have a field called ActiveIndicator. If the doctor is currently providing services to at least 1 location, the ActiveIndicator will be set to 1. If not, it should be set to 0.
I tried querying the DrData table using a distinct and this will give me one row per doctor. However, it won't let me properly set the ActiveIndicator column value based on the DrStartDt and DrEndDt columsn. To be considered active, a doctor would need a DrStartDt that falls before CurDate and a DrEndDt that is null.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

your first issue is that the table is not properly normalized.  next you can look up the BETWEEN operator and depending on which database you use, the NVL operator.  this will get you quickly to the list of active records.  then you will need to join correctly to each doctor.

Thank you for the comments. I figured it out. I first write a select distinct from MdData to a temp table. This gets rid of the duplicates. I also set the ActiveIndicator row in temp table to 0. I then write a second query that I use to update the ActiveIndicator column in the temp table. Using the date qualification checks on DrStartDate and DrEndDate. Setting ActiveIndicator to 1 if criteria is met.

I first write a select distinct from MdData to a temp table. This gets rid of the duplicates. I also set the ActiveIndicator row in temp table to 0. I then write a second query that I use to update the ActiveIndicator column in the temp table. Using the date qualification checks on DrStartDate and DrEndDate. Setting ActiveIndicator to 1 if criteria is met.

If you have a primary key/unique key, say: DrId, then you could write like this:
select DrId
     , case 
         when sum( case when DrStartDt < CurDate and DrEndDt is null 
                        then 1
                        else 0 
                   end) > 0
             then 1 
             else 0 
      end as ActiveIndicator
from DrData
group by DrId

Because this produces one row per DrId, and for each row (each Dr) it counts the rows (adds 1) where the date condition is met, and if the total is more than zero then returns 1 as the ActuveIndicator.
You could also use other aggregation functions to achieve it.
